# Positioning Text Box Inside Excel Chart

Tags: excel, excel-charts

An Excel chart can include a text box as follows.

[image]

A user can exactly specify the width and height of this box—for example, 2 in by 1 in. Then, can the user determine the vertical and horizontal position of this box relative to the chart? Using a mouse is easy, but I wonder whether that box can be exactly located at the northwest corner of the chart with 0.1 in vertical and horizontal margins from the top and left, respectively.

Comment: It's definitely doable. You should record a macro with the macro recorder and examine the resulting code.

Comment: A textbox can be placed in any location you want. However, it's on the same pane as the chart. Therefore it's possible to place it either behind or over the chart. There is a property for that. The textbox also has a `TopLeftCell` property which has `Top` and `Left` properties. You can set the textbox's `Top` and `Left` properties relative to them. The chart object also has `Top` and `Left` properties and you can place the textbox relative to those. I presume that the chart is a member of the worksheet's Shapes collection, as is the Tbx.

Comment: Using a macro seems to be inevitable. As I want the chart to include the text box, it seems I need to use `Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft` or `IncrementTop`. Or `Shapes.Left` or `Shapes.Top`. Thanks.